# How to draw two textures with alpha in webgl

Tags: javascript, html, opengl-es, webgl

I want to draw a texture and draw another with transparent background on top. So the transparent parts show the first texture.

I call `gl.clear` once and then `gl.drawElements` for each texture on render. But the output is, the transparent texture with transparent parts are black that is the clear color. As if the first texture has never been drawn but the second texture is drawn only with transparent background. How to fix this?

```
  gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);


gl.clear()

for each texture:

  gl.drawElements();
```

Another rendering issue is, for textures A and B I call gl.drawElements for texture A and then B. But A goes on top of B on output.

So the problem was gl.enable(DEPTH_TEST);

I removed it and it works fine now. I wonder why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the problem was `gl.enable(DEPTH_TEST)`;
>   I removed it and it works fine now. I wonder why.

I'd conclude from this that you draw both textured obnjects at the same distance from the camera. The default value for `glDepthFunc` is `GL_LESS`, so a fragment will pass the depth test only if it has a lower window space z valuie than what is in the depth buffer already. When you draw the first textured quad, the depth buffer will be set to these values, and you need to move your second object closer to make it pass the depth test, or set `glDepthFunc` to `GL_LEQUEAL` meaning less than *or equal*. However, since you do not need the depth test at all in your scenario, disabling it will be the most efficient approach performance-wise anyway.